# Python - Running Count on conditions within a group

Tags: python, count

I have the following data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','D','E','E','F'], 
'Button': ['Begin','Begin','End','Begin','End','Begin','End','Begin','Begin','End','Begin','Begin','End','End']
})
```

By unique 'ID', I want to group rows together by a running count until the string 'End' appears in the Button column. For example, the 5 rows that assigned to ID = 'C' should be split out into two groups (1 and 2) since there are two rows that contain 'End'. ID = 'D' should not be grouped because there is no row assigned to Id = 'D' with the string 'End'.

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','D','E','E','F'], 
'Button': ['Begin','Begin','End','Begin','End','Begin','End','Begin','Begin','End','Begin','Begin','End','End'],
'Count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,1]
})
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: I've read and re-read the problem statement, but I just can't comprehend what determines a group or the counts.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can start by making every "End" a 1 and everything else a NaN.  Then for each ID group, we can take the cumulative sum (couting the Ends) and back-fill to set all the Begins to the appropriate number.  Finally we can fill any remaining NaNs with 0, because they're the cases where there weren't any Ends in a group.

IOW:

```
In [263]: ends = (data["Button"] == "End").replace(False, np.nan)

In [264]: data["Count"] = ends.groupby(data["ID"]).apply(
          lambda x: x.cumsum().bfill()).fillna(0).astype(int)

In [265]: data
Out[265]: 
   ID Button  Count
0   A  Begin      1
1   A  Begin      1
2   A    End      1
3   B  Begin      1
4   B    End      1
5   C  Begin      1
6   C    End      1
7   C  Begin      2
8   C  Begin      2
9   C    End      2
10  D  Begin      0
11  E  Begin      1
12  E    End      1
13  F    End      1
```